# Loop over array and replacing with regex returns empty string

Tags: php, regex, foreach

I have a String which contains substrings which I have to replace. The substrings are stored in an array. When I loop through the array everything works fine, until the array has more than 120 entries.

```
foreach ( $activeTags as $k => $v ) {
  $find = $activeTags[$k]['Tag']['tag'];
  $replace = 'that';
  $pattern = "/\#\#[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\#\#.*\b$find\b.*\#\#END_[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\#\#|$find/"; 
  $sText = '<p>Do not replace ##DS## this ##END_DS## replace this.</p>';

  $sText = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use($find, $replace){
    if($match[0] == $find){
      return($replace);
    }else{
      return($match[0]);
    }
  }, $sText);
}
```

when count($activeTags) == 121 i only get an empty string.

Has onyone an idea why this happens?

Comment: Try to `var_dump` your array?

Comment: manually setting the array with less than 121 entries works fine, dynamically too.

Comment: Possibly there is something odd with your 121st tag.

Comment: nope, the 121tag is correct. i replaced it with other tags and still the problem was tag no121

Comment: Can you add the `$activeTags` array content with 121 entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this improved pattern:

```
$pattern = "~##([a-zA-Z]{2})##.*?\b$find\b.*?##END_\1##|$find~s";
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Discussion

The `~s` flag indicates that dot (`.`) should match newlines. In your example, `p` tags are metionned. So I guess its an html fragment. Since newlines are alloed in html, I have added the `~s` flag. More over, I have made the pattern more readable by:

- using custom pattern boundaries: `/` becomes `~`, you avoid escape anything...
- replacing duplicate subpatterns: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]` becomes `[a-zA-Z]{2}`
- taking advantage of the sequence `##DS## ##END_DS##`. I use a backreference (`\1`) for matching what was found in the first matching group (Group 1 in the above image).

Comment: @user2641845 No you can ... don't you ? :)